# buffuring in UDP connection at the client

Tags: udp, udpclient

for real time application, if I use  UDP  protocol to send data and the buffer of the client is full then the OS(interested in linux) or UDP protocol or whatever will:
1.replace the old data in the client buffer with new data. 
2."drop" the new data and keep the old data until it's used/processed?

Comment: @EJP is there anyone to do (1)?